# Load forajax required js files parallel

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I need a fast methode to load required js files for a single page application.

For example, there are 5 js files with depends to each other.

Now my ajax returns the new content and a list of required js files.

How can i manage to load all files paralle without getting script errors. like xy is not defined?

if i do it parallel:

```
// Load required js files.
var items_to_load = files_to_load.length;
$.each(files_to_load, function (index, file) {
    // Load script file if not allready loadet.
    $.getScript(file, function (script, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        items_to_load --;

        // On last file call callback function.
        if (items_to_load === 0 && typeof success_callback === 'function') {
            success_callback();
        }
    });
});
```

I never can be shure that the first file is allready loadet when the 3rd is done.
So i get sometimes xy is not defined.

If i load it sequencial.

```
// Load file by file.
var load_scripts = function () {
    var file = files_to_load.shift();
    // Load script file if not allready loadet.
    getScript(file, function (script, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        // On last file call callback function.
        if (files_to_load.length === 0) {
            if (typeof success_callback === 'function') {
                success_callback();
            }
        } else {
            // Load next script.
            load_scripts();
        }
    });
};
load_scripts();
```

it takes mutch more time.

Is it possible to tell the browser to load all files but interpret it first if all are loadet?
Like it qould do on normal page load with allot of

Comment: So, "a" depends on "b" depends on "c" depends on "d", etc.? In that case, you're doomed :)

Comment: Don't re-invent the wheel, use [requirejs](http://requirejs.org/).

Answer (score 0):

Edit, updated

Try (this pattern)

```
// $(document).trigger("_ready", [ false ]) : hold 
// $(document).trigger("_ready", [ true ]) : release
$(document).trigger("_ready", [ false ]);
        var list = ["http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/jquery-ui.min.js"
                   , "http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"
                   , "http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.js"
                   , "http://code.jquery.com/color/jquery.color-2.1.2.min.js"  
                   , "http://code.jquery.com/qunit/qunit-1.14.0.js" 
                   ];
        var _complete = [];
        $.each(list, function (index, value) {
            $.getScript(value)
                .done(function (data, textStatus, jqxhr) {
                _complete.push(textStatus + " at " + $.now());
                if (_complete.length === list.length) {
                    alert("list done" 
                         + "\n\n list: " + list.length 
                         + "\n\n" + list.toString() 
                         + "\n\n _complete: " 
                         + _complete.length 
                         + "\n\n" + _complete);
                    // toggle `_ready` parameter,
                    // `ready` : true
                    $(document).trigger("_ready", [ true ]);
                    // do stuff
                };
            });
        });
        $(document).on("_ready", function(e, ready) {
          // do stuff 
          // after `list` iteration, `$.getScript()` pieces complete
          // if `ready` === false,
          // block within `if` statement will _not_ run
          if (ready === true && (jQuery.QUnit 
               && jQuery.color 
               && jQuery.migrate 
               && jQuery.migrate 
               && jQuery.mobile 
               && jQuery.ui) in window)
          {
              console.log(_complete);
              alert("ready at " + $.now() +"\n"+ e.type +" ready: "+ ready);
            console.log(jQuery.ui.version
                       , jQuery.mobile.version
                       , jQuery.migrate in window
                       , jQuery.color in window
                       , jQuery.QUnit in window);
          };
        });
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/guest271314/AE7zR/

Comment: Sorry but the holdReady(false) just force the docuemnt.ready to be fired one. But it dont solve the depeneds between the single js files. Here an example: http://www.file-upload.net/download-9180057/js_requirement_ajax_fix.tar.gz.html

Comment: `$.holdReady(true)` should hold the calling of any of the pieces in `list` until _all_ of the pieces in `list` are loaded into document. `$.holdReady(false)` releases "hold" on `.ready()` only after _all_ pieces in `list` are loaded. Only then does `if` check for each loaded piece being `property` of `window` object. Not certain what "depends between the single js files" means. Please illuminate ?  Not certain what looking for/at at link? At OP "Is it possible to tell the browser to load all files but interpret it first if all are loadet?". Accomplished _twice_ at `if` statements. Thanks

Comment: As an explanation: When you always would use jquery holdReady. would work. But we use also libraries such as blockly which does not rely on ready function so they depends on the correct order of loading files. Just think of plain javascript without that wrapper function $(document).ready();..